# serving video from appengine blobstore behaves differently to static file

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, video, blobstore

I'm having trouble serving video from the app engine blobstore, to a html5  tag, video seems to hang on the last frame preventing the `ended` trigger being fired which i need to use. I am also unable to seek in the video or force the video to play with right click. If I upload the file as a static file then the file works as expected, triggers are fired and seeking is enabled.

Here's the file served from the blobstore:

http://jsfiddle.net/AvqUy/18/

And the same video served as a static file:

http://jsfiddle.net/AvqUy/19/

I's this a limitation of the blobstore or am i doing somethign wrong?

also heres my code for handling the video files:

```
class VideoFileHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        video = db.get(self.request.get('video_id'))
        if video.video_file:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mpeg'
            self.response.out.write(video.video_file)
        else:
            self.response.out.write('No video file')
```

Comment: I can not help but think why would you serve video from a database, anydatabase, use AWS S3 instead, but I don't know the answer to your actual question, sorry.

Comment: Why would you not use video from a database, it seems that a few questions asked ok so say that the blob store is a good way to store any large files, photos/videos etc

Comment: There is a 1MB limit. That is not "large". Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362001/store-photos-in-blobstore-or-as-blobs-in-datastore-which-is-better-more-effici

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using send_blob.

[Here's an example](http://audio-test.appspot.com/) I did that illustrates serving using send_blob and from google cloud storage using html audio & video tags..

Comment: oh interesting, what does the code look looke to retrieve the blob using send_blob

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers