# Should I store product images as db.ListProperty(db.Blob) or db.ListProperty(db.Key)?

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, datastore

I'm currently storing uploaded images for a given product, as follow:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    images= db.ListProperty(db.Blob)
    # More properties ...
```

And I retrieve them with:

```
class ImageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        productKey = cgi.escape(self.request.get('id'))

        if productKey:
            try:
                product = Product.get(db.Key(productKey))
                if product and product.images:
                    idx = 0 # if not img is passed, return the first one
                    imageIndex = cgi.escape(self.request.get('img'))
                    if imageIndex:
                        imageIndex = int(imageIndex)
                        if imageIndex > 0 and imageIndex < len(product.images):
                            idx = imageIndex

                    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
                    self.response.out.write(str(product.images[idx]))
                    return
                self.redirect('/img/image-missing.jpg')
                return
            except:
                self.redirect('/img/image-404.jpg')
                return
        self.redirect('/img/image-404.jpg')
```

By calling `/image?id={{productkey}}&img={{imageindex}}`.

Now considering:

- Datastore costs
- CPU/memory/time costs
- Possible migration to another app/datastore or even to amazon, etc.
- The ability to return resized images for thumbnails display, etc.
- Other factors that I haven't considered

Should I keep it like this, or should I have a separate model for an image, which only contains a `db.BlobProperty`, and have a `db.ListProperty(db.Key)` instead in the product model?

I'm not sure if keeping the images as blobs inside of the Product automatically fetches them when I get() a product (which would be bad), or if it reduces datastore accesses because I don't have to get another image entity.

Finally, any suggestions to improve this python code (that's a lot of redirect, return and conditions) would be surely appreciated as well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider that each datastore entity is bound to 1MB size, then storing a list of Blobs into one entity can easily be a problem. It's better to store each image in a separate model and keep a list of Keys for your Product model.

Comment: Oh. Then considering the 1MB limit, that means I wouldn't be able to store large images even in their own entity. What are the downsides of using the blobstore instead of the datastore to store images? Depending on that, I might simply limit the size of the uploaded images instead.

Comment: After searching for this particular blobstore vs datastore question: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362001/store-photos-in-blobstore-or-as-blobs-in-datastore-which-is-better-more-effici and will definitely get rid of the ListProperty(db.Blob) and unless advised otherwise will most likely use the blobstore.