# ndb.BlobProperty vs BlobStore: which is more private and more secure

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

I have been reading all over stackoverflow concerning datastore vs blobstore for storing and retrieving image files. Everything is pointing towards blobstore except one: privacy and security.

In the datastore, the photos of my users are private: I have full control on who gets a blob. In the blobstore, however, anyone who knows the url can conceivable access my users photos? Is that true?

Here is a quote that is supposed to give me peace of mind, but it's still not clear. So anyone with the blob key can still access the photos? (from [Store Photos in Blobstore or as Blobs in Datastore - Which is better/more efficient /cheaper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362001/store-photos-in-blobstore-or-as-blobs-in-datastore-which-is-better-more-effici))

> the way you serve a value out of the Blobstore is to accept a request
>   to the app, then respond with the X-AppEngine-BlobKey header with the
>   key. App Engine intercepts the outgoing response and replaces the body
>   with the Blobstore value streamed directly from the service. Because
>   app logic sets the header in the first place, the app can implement
>   any access control it wants. There is no default URL that serves
>   values directly out of the Blobstore without app intervention.

All of this is to ask: Which is more private and more secure for trafficking images, and why: datastore or blobstore? Or, hey, google-cloud-storage (which I know nothing about presently)

Comment: I am also looking into this, I think the blobstore is the best for controlling access via handlers or services, which can have user access control

Comment: And blobstore is similar to cloud storage from what I have read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url then yes, [the url returned is public](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url).  However the url returned is not guessable from a blob's key, nor does the url even exist before calling get_serving_url.  (Or after calling delete_serving_url).

If you need access control on top of the data in the blobstore [you can write your own handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob) and add the access control there.

Answer (score 0):

`BlobProperty` is just as private and secure as `BlobStore`, all depends on your application which serves the requests. your application can implement any permission checking before sending the contents to the user, so I don't see any difference as long as you serve all the images yourself and don't intentionally create publicly available URLs.

Actually, I would not even thinlk about storing photos in the `BlobProperty`, because this way the data ends up in the database instead of the `BlobStore` and it costs significantly more to store data in the database. `BlobStore`, on the other hand, is cheap and convenient.