# Store uploaded file data in Blob

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In my GAE app I want to store the uploaded file in a ndb.BlobProperty . How can I assign the uploaded file content to this property.

Further more is BlobProperty the standard approach to store user uploaded files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551796/ndb-blobproperty-vs-blobstore-which-is-more-private-and-more-secure)

Simply put, assign a serving url that you pass to a handler setup by routes

handlers

```
class GetBlobstoreUrl(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload/')
        self.response.out.write(upload_url)

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads()
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
```

model

```
class SomeModel(ndb.Model):
  avatar = ndb.BlobProperty()
```

Comment: 2 things 

Does changing the parent of the handler class from webapp2.RequestHandler to blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler change the rest of the implementation? As I have written all the handling of rest of the form fields in it.

How I would change this upload_files[0] to handle multiple files.

Comment: The blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler uses get_uploads to get the blob_info, that's why its in its own class and each url points to a single file so it cant point to multiple file (you can create multiple upload urls though) You should be able to google for complete examples that will make it even clearer